deluge script consumption of api with content type as multipart/formdata
I'm currently working on a project within Zoho Books where I need to dynamically generate PDF documents by leveraging an external API. The API requires multipart form data for communication.
My objective is to execute a Deluge script within Zoho Books to consume this API and generate the PDFs. Here's the approach I've considered:
res = invokeurl
[
url :endpoint
type :POST
headers:headers
content-type:"multipart/form-data"
files:list_of_key_value
detailed:true
];
